# Raspberry Pi 2 not booting [SD card all fine]

Tags: boot, sd-card

Both leds stay constantly on. So fault must be in sd card. I formatted the sd cards in full and copied the files as it is done. Did this for a new sd card. I tried sdformatter and windows' own formatting tool. But it just doesn't boot up.

Comment: "So fault must be in sd card" So you are now an expert! But you haven't even bothered to tell us what you have tried or even what OS.

Comment: How, exactly, did you format the SD card?

Answer (score 2):

> Both leds stay constantly on.

This is exactly the same thing that will happen if you plug it in with *no* SD card inserted.  Try it.

So either:

1. The card is formatted incorrectly.
2. The SD card is one the reader doesn't like; this was more an issue with the original models, but I believe people have had problems with certain 64 GB cards on the microSD models (+/2/3/0).  Try a completely different card.
3. The Pi is broken.

Ruling out #2 is easy unless you are in a strange remote land where only one make and model of SD card is available, so that really leaves #1 and #3.  Unless you have another Pi, you can't even infer much about #3, so which one you want to pick depends on how tenacious you want to be focussing on #1.